# Replace single quotes for strings divided by blank space from variable

Tags: bash, solaris, variable, read, rewrite

I'm writing a bash script where I'm reading in a variable via `read` this two strings:

```
log.*.console.log log.*.log
```

They are separated by space.

How can I rewrite the strings that the output from the variable for the next program called in the script will have them in this form ? `'log.*.console.log' 'log.*.log'`

I was trying sed and awk but somehow without success.

The whole script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$*" ] ; then
echo "USAGE: ./some text"
exit 1

else

echo "some text"
read varlogname

i=1
for file in $@
do
echo "Doing" $file
GTAR=$(gtar -xvf $file --wildcards --ignore-case --no-anchored "$varlogname")

for file in ${GTAR[*]}
do
mv $file $file"."${i}
i=$((i+1))
done
done
echo "Files extracted."
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: and not sure why you need to add the quotes... perhaps going through this might solve your issue: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: @Sundeep

I'm having this in my script `GTAR=$(gtar -xvf $file --wildcards --ignore-case --no-anchored "$varlogname")` inside a loop. where the `$varlogname` is the variable which I'm reading in via `read`, the problem is  `gtar` needs this as a separator `''` between files. But since it's a loop it has to be inside `""` within the script.

Comment: @Sundeep added the whole script into original post, so it's better to read.

Comment: check you script with http://www.shellcheck.net/ correct the errors and update this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want to give the single quotes to `gtar`. In a command such as `somecmd 'foo bar' 'files*.log'`, the shell will handle the quotes, they tell it not to treat special characters specially, and pass `somecmd` the arguments `foo bar` and `files*.log`. Unix programs do not get the command-line as one string, but a number of argument strings, it is the shell that does the splitting of the command-line to strings.

If you want to `read` multiple values in Bash, you could use `read -a array`, and then hand the array to the command.

```
  -a array  assign the words read to sequential indices of the array
            variable ARRAY, starting at zero
```

i.e.

```
read -a filenames
gtar "${filenames[@]}"
```

Indexing the array with `[@]` (in quotes) expands to the array members as separate words, which is what you want.

Also, you have `for file in ${GTAR[*]}`. That looks like accessing `GTAR` as an array, but it isn't one, you've just assigned the output of the `gtar` command to it, as a string. In this case `${GTAR[*]}` is the same as `$GTAR`. Since the expansion isn't quoted the string undergoes word-splitting at this point, which by default splits on whitespaces. But, after that, the words are *also* taken as filename globs and expanded to matching filenames.

As long as your filenames don't contain whitespace or glob characters (`*?[]`, this is fine. But in general, it's not something you want to do.

For proper arrays, you probably always want to use `"${array[@]}"` instead of `[*]`.

See: [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http:///questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)